# NSString to NSDate and then changing the format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I thought I had the "hard" part done but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I retrieve a date from an RSS feed that I would like to convert to a NSDate and then change it to the simple format (MM/DD/YYYY).  The date comes in this format on the RSS feed:

Thu, 1 Nov 2012 17:41:56 CST

I have converted it to an NSDate successfully.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
//[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; Using these seems to change what it expects from the string I guess?
//[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
date = [df dateFromString:string];
[self.tempItem setPubDate:[df dateFromString:string]];
NSLog(@"%@", [df dateFromString:string]);
```

So I get my date just fine, but like I said before I want to just convert it to a simple date.
When I use setDateStyle I end up with null values.  When I don't use it, I get correct dates, just not in the format I want it to end up being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just not in the format I want it to end up being.

Because `NSLog()` doesn't know about the format - how would it? `NSDate` doesn't have any built-in "format". You have to obtain a string from the date object by using `NSDateFormatter` once again. Basically the workflow you'll have to use is roughly:

- retrieve an NSString from the RSS feed
- Create a date formatter
- Set its format according to the format of the string
- Get an `NSDate` object from the date formatter
- Re-set the format of the `NSDateFormatter` to the format you desire
- Obtain a properly formatted `NSString` using the date and the date formatter objects.

Comment: Thank you. I did not originally understand that the formatting did not actually change the NSDate object but how it appears when going out to strings and such.  Since this was going on a tableview anyways I now know I can wait all the way until I set the label text to format it how I want.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another NSDateFormatter to convert NSDate to NSString

> NSDateFormatter *dfSimple = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
>
> [dfSimple setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
>
> [dfSimple setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
>
> NSLog(@"%@", [dfSimple stringFromDate: date]);

It is better to create 2 NSDateFormatter objects in this case